# Javascript unable to return variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays with objects that looks like this:

```
var data = [
[{'name':'John', 'value':2},
{'name':'Randy', 'value':4}
],

[{'name':'Sarah', 'value':10},
{'name':'Julie', 'value':10}
]
];
```

I want to iterate through each array and add up `value`s and store the totals in an array. What I came up with looks like this:

```
function add(accumulator, a) {
    return accumulator + a;
}

var totals = [];

var yExtent = data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(jtem) {
    var subTotals = [];
    subTotals.push(jtem.value);
    return subTotals;
  })
  var localTotal = subTotals.reduce(add,0);
  totals.push(localTotal);
  return totals;
});

console.log(totals)
```

However, this results in the error: "subTotals is not defined"

### Question

Is this happening because `subTotals` is not in the same scope as the other part of the function? If so, how should I proceed? I cannot put `var localTotal = subTotals.reduce(add,0);` in scope because the `forEach()` would calculate it too frequently and give me the wrong values. How should I modify this code to return my inner `forEach()` calculations to the outer?

Comment: Except for a useless `undefined`, `forEach` doesn't return anything. Besides that, you have the scope issue of that variable.

Comment: move `var subTotals = [];` one line up out of the inner `forEach`

Comment: ^--- this, and also remove the `return total` (which is doing nothing anyway).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Lux That worked, thanks! I'm starting to second guess `forEach` for this type of task. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: its perfectly fine to use `forEach`!. your problem is that you've defined `subTotals` inside the `forEach` and used it outside later. But a simple `map` would be nicer.

Comment: @ArashHowaida `map` + `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is for side effects.  You really want to write your transforms using transforming functions instead of side effects.  First, it will be shorter.  Second, it will be clearer - you don't want a side effect, you want a pure transformation, and your code will reflect that.  Using the same code, but with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead results in this:

```
var totals = data.map(item => {
  var localTotal = item.map(datum => datum.value).reduce(add, 0);
  return localTotal;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like

```
function selectValue(item) {
  return item.value;
}

const totals = data.map(
  subList => subList.map(selectValue)
                    .reduce(add, 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declaration of subTotals outside of the forEach loop like this-

Also you shouldn't reuse item.

```
function add(accumulator, a) {
    return accumulator + a;
}

var totals = [];

var yExtent = data.forEach(function(item) {
    var subTotals = [];
    item.forEach(function(subItem) {
        var subs = [];
        subTotals.push(subItem.value);
        return subs;
    })
    var localTotal = subTotals.reduce(add,0);
    totals.push(localTotal);
    return totals;
});

console.log(totals)
```

This will still give you a multi-dimensional array so you may want to change the console log to console.log(totals.flat(2)).

Or you may want to add the numbers..

Answer (score 0):

The array.forEach function is made so that it is impossible for it to return any value.  There is not a way to over-ride this behavior.  It's something they did under the hood.  So, all you can do with .forEach is go through an array and do something with the items that are stored to the array, like console.log() them, etc.